# Building a WHERE clause based on whether a field is NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have a function that has a condition in the `WHERE` clause that compares a field (`DATE` type) to a date that is passed to the function.

On occasion the date field is `NULL`.  When this occurs I would like to have the comparison to always return true.

What I have currently come up with:

```
WHERE NVL(table.from_date, TO_DATE('01-JAN-1900')) <= TO_DATE(input_date)
```

Is there a better way of accomplishing this? For example, building a `WHERE` clause based on whether `table.from_date` is `NULL`. If `table.from_date` is `NULL` then the `WHERE` clause is `table.from_date <= TO_DATE(input_date)`; otherwise the `WHERE` clause doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to add a `NULL` check with `OR`:

```
WHERE (table.from_date IS NULL 
      OR table.from_date <= TO_DATE(input_date))
```

This way, if the from_date is null, it will evaluate to true.